# Ubuntu server reinstalled, ghost gnome desktop returns?

Tags: server, reinstall

I am experiencing a weird situation:

I was using Ubuntu Server LTS and later installed the Gnome desktop. Now I've decided to do a fresh install of Ubuntu Server to return to just the CLI. The re-installation went well, but the `/home` directory still has the files from before.

I restarted the computer and had a graphical login again. It looks like Gnome is still installed, but it's not the same as before. The programs list is different and there is no Terminal that I can find.

Here are my questions:

- How did this happen?
- Is the Desktop Environment somehow located in the `/home` directory?
- Did it re-install the packages?

I don't understand this, but it was really weird to see a GUI when I wanted a regular Ubuntu Server installation.

How can I get a plain Ubuntu Server install again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you configured the first Ubuntu Server installation, there's a possibility that you set `/home` to be on its own partition and, depending on how you reinstalled the most current Ubuntu Server installation, there's a possibility that you instructed it to install overtop the existing installation. This could result in the weirdness that you've experienced.

If you would like to have a vanilla Ubuntu Server again, you will need to remove all partitions from the storage devices, *then* install.

Here's one way to do it:

1. Boot with the Ubuntu Server installation media and begin the installation process
2. When you get to the "Guided Storage Configuration" part, choose "Custom Storage Layout":
   [image: Guided Storage Configuration]
   Then press <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>⇣</kbd> to get to the `[ Done     ]` item and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Under `[Used Devices]`, delete every partition you see *except* `partition 1`:
   [image: Storage Configuration]
   <sub>**Note:** If you try to delete `partition 1`, the installer will complain that you cannot remove it.</sub>
4. When asked to confirm, choose the `[ Delete    ]` option:
   [image: Are you sure?]
   Do this for all partitions on all storage devices (except the `bios_grub` partition, of course).
5. After all of the partitions are removed, create a new one:
   [image: Add GPT Partition]
   <sub>**Note:** You can do this from both the "Available Devices" and "Used Devices" section.</sub>
6. Set the new partition(s) to use as much space as you'd like:
   [image: Adding GPT Partition]
7. Double-check that everything is good:
   [image: Confirm those numbers]
8. You will be asked to "confirm the destructive action", and you will want to choose `[ Continue   ]` to write the new partition definitions to the storage devices:
   [image: Confirm Destruction!]
9. Carry on with the installation ...
   [image: Profile setup]
10. Watch the little spinner twirl while having a cup of coffee:
    [image: Twirl, Spinner! Twirl!]
    Is it just me, or does the spinner for `running 'curtain hook'` twirl faster than the spinner for `downloading and installing security updates`?
11. Reboot.
12. Enjoy your CLI:
    [image: Behold!]

After signing in, you should find that — so long as you deleted all previously existing partitions — there is no sign of your previous files, directories, preferences, or a GUI.